# notepad++ theme colors weird appearance

Tags: lua, notepad++

My question is regarding Notepad++, I'm trying to use a theme (that came with the installation), as I think a darker editor would be better for my eyes, either way for some reason the code appears as this:

[image: img]

this is for Lua and I can't seem to find any settings for this. It's obviously not workable this way. I also tried using github's editor but it wasn't really functioning the way I wanted.

Comment: what Notepad++ version are You using? Which Lua syntax highlighting plugin are You using? What theme are You using "to make it darker"?

Comment: No matter which theme I try, it is the same result(trying those that came with the program). Notepad++ v6.4.5 and https://code.google.com/p/npp-gmod-lua/